# Javafx and Jersey: A message body reader for Java class and MIME media type application/xml was not found

Tags: jersey, javafx-2

I've made a javafx client which request a Web service via Jersey.

Here is the ws code :

```
public List<Document> findDocuments(String query, int row, int start) {

    String serviceUri = "/articleservices/searchservice/fulltext";
    String queryParams = "/" + query + "/" + row + "/" + start;

    String queryUrl = StringUtils.join(new String[]{
        AppProperties.SEARCH_WS_BASE_ADDRESS, serviceUri, queryParams});
    log.debug("queryUrl: {}", queryUrl);

    SearchResult searchResult = new SearchResult();

    try {
        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = client.resource(queryUrl);
        ClientResponse response = webResource.
                accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).
                get(ClientResponse.class);

        if (response.getStatus() == 200) {
            searchResult = response.getEntity(SearchResult.class);
            log.debug("NbResults: {}", searchResult.getNbResultItem());

        } else {
            log.debug("Error");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.debug(e.getMessage());
    }

    DocumentFactory docFactory = new DocumentFactory();

    return docFactory.createDocuments(searchResult);
}
```

I've declared these dependencies in the pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
   <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
   <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
```

It works fine when I execute the unit test, I get "NbResults" result. 
But with the javafx client, the query return a status 200 and the response Content-Type is application/xml. But It won't map the entity and the WS result. I get this error:

```
AM com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse getEntity

Grave: A message body reader for Java class com.mycompany.search.beans.SearchResult, and Java type class com.mycompany.search.beans.SearchResult, and MIME media type application/xml was not found

Grave: The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
    */* ->
      com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
      com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
      com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
```

Any help please ?

== UPDATE ==

The SearchResult class looks like this !

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "SEARCH-RESULT")
public class SearchResult implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 87551L;

    // Nombre de résultat trouvé
    private long nbResultItem;

    // Liste contenant le format pivot de la bcp
    private List<SearchResultItem> resultItems;

    @XmlElement(name = "DOC-NUMBER")
    public long getNbResultItem() {
            return nbResultItem;
    }

    public void setNbResultItem(long nbResultItem) {
            this.nbResultItem = nbResultItem;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "DOC-RESULTS")
    public List<SearchResultItem> getResultItems() {
            return resultItems;
    }

    public void setResultItems(List<SearchResultItem> resultItems) {
            this.resultItems = resultItems;
    }

}
```

Comment: How does the `SearchResult` class look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've used org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate instead. It works perfectly !
http://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate